# How to refresh a Vaadin accordion dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, accordion, vaadin

I'm having a little problem with accordion. When I try for example delete one tab of accordion I don't find any way to do it. Anyone know how I can do this?

Here some of my code.

```
public ResponseUI(final Window mainWindow, boolean allowSave, final Context c) {
    InjectHelper.inject(this);
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);

    // TODO add user code here
    //TODO: add responses to accordion

    List<Templates> templatesReenvia = templateBusinessManager.getAllTemplatesResposta();        
    boolean bandera = true;
    for(Templates tmpl : templatesReenvia) {
        accordion_respostes.addTab(new PlantillaView(mainWindow, panel_1, c, tmpl), tmpl.getSubject());
    }
    panel_1.addComponent(new ResponseForm(mainWindow,allowSave));

    panel_respostes.setScrollable(true);    
    button_1.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {    
            final Window dialog = new Window("Edició de plantilla");
            dialog.setModal(true);
            mainWindow.addWindow(dialog);
            dialog.addComponent(new PlantillaForm(mainWindow, c, false));
            dialog.setWidth("85%");
        }
    });
}
```

In `templateBusinessManager0` I have CRUD methods, so I only need to know how to refresh my accordion when one of this methods occurs. Hope someone have the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you remove with [removeComponent](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#removeComponent(com.vaadin.ui.Component)) or replace with [replaceComponent](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html#replaceComponent(com.vaadin.ui.Component,%20com.vaadin.ui.Component)) like in any other component container.  if your components can not change their state on their own, you have to swap them out.

Comment: I need to refresh not to remove :/

Comment: Remove + Add = refresh, since it's not the same object

Comment: @GooDFighTy there is also replaceComponent.  your first sentence mentioned "delete" so i thought, this was your sole problem

Answer (score 0):

This sample app replaces contents of one tab with other content when clicking a button. Please also not that the Accordion/TabSheet does not replace the metadata (e.g. caption) of the tab automatically, but copies this from the old tab's metadata. In this example the caption always says "*Tab 1*" even if the content itself is swapped.

```
public class AccordionUI extends UI {

private Accordion accordion;
private Panel tab1, tab2, tab3;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
    setContent(hl);

    tab1 = new Panel("Tab 1");
    tab2 = new Panel("Tab 2");
    tab3 = new Panel("Tab 3");

    accordion = new Accordion(tab1, tab2);
    hl.addComponent(accordion);

    Button button = new Button("Replace");
    button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            accordion.replaceComponent(tab1, tab3);
        }
    });
    hl.addComponent(button);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin states (see https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.accordion.html): You can use an Accordion identically to a TabSheet.

If you have a look at the TabSheet documentation you'll find something like this:

```
tabsheet.removeTab(tab);
```

And this:

```
tabsheet.addTab(myTab).setCaption("My Tab");
```

So you may refresh the title, close the tab or just change the component inside by using the replaceComponent() method.

Comment: Accordion had also mehod `addTab(Component,caption)` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove specific tab, you can use `removeTab(Tab tabComponent)`
 - tab param can you get by the `getTab(component)` (component is that one, which are you using while calls `addTab(Component newTabComponent)` method :o)
(or direct way `replaceComponent(oldComponent, newComponent)` should works also)

If you need to remove all accord tabs, I'm using `accordionInstance.removeAllComponents()`, but if `removeTab` or `replaceComponent` sucks, there's also way- you can add tab with some specific layout and you call `removeComponents()` and `addComponent(newComponent)` on that layout :)